# How to apply gsub on exact words instead of characters

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame in R containing a column "CountryCode".

I would like to select valid Countries and replace all other codes with "OtherCountry". So I wrote:

```
Valid_Countries <- c("US", "CA", "JP", "AU", "DE", "IT", "ES", "FR", "UK", "FI", "SE", "NO")

levels(Orders2$CountryCode) <- gsub(paste0("[^", paste(Valid_Countries, collapse=""), "]+"), "OtherCountry", levels(Orders2$CountryCode))
```

which *almost* works. My problem is that Country codes like "BE" is replaced with "OtherCountryE" (I guess it is because "E" is included in the Valid_Countries).

How can I say "just consider the entire code"?

Comment: Try `paste0("(?s)^(?!(?:", paste(Valid_Countries, collapse="|"), ")$).*")` and add `perl=TRUE`. See https://ideone.com/o6tQdP

Comment: I did not understand exactly how, but it works! :) I need to study a bit more to completely understand this code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
levels(Orders2$CountryCode)[
    !(levels(Orders2$CountryCode) %in% Valid_Countries)
    ] <- "OtherCountry
```